# change a key to a dictionary in google app engine - solved using a different approach

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm having trouble changing a key value to a dictionary value

```
def get(self):

  #Get all the Subjects
  subjects = ndb.gql('SELECT name,order FROM Subject ORDER BY order ASC')
  values = {'subjects':subjects}

  #Get all the Contents
  for subject in subjects:
    contents = ndb.gql('SELECT * FROM Content WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ORDER BY order ASC',subject.key)
    values[subject.name] = contents #***HERE is the issue***
```

Rather than getting a dictionary

`value = {key:value}`

I'm trying to get

`value = {{key:value}:value}`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

---

**EDIT:**
When I try

`values['subject':subject.name] = contents`

I get the error

`TypeError: unhashable type`

---

**Solved:** with a different approach:

```
def get(self):
  #Get all the Subjects
  subjects = ndb.gql('SELECT name,order FROM Subject ORDER BY order ASC')
  values = {'subjects':subjects}
  #Get all the Contents
  values['contents'] = []
  for subject in subjects:
    #Formatting HTML output
    subjectAll = subject.name + ' ' + subject.order
    contents = ndb.gql('SELECT name,order FROM Content WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ORDER BY order ASC',subject.key)
    values['contents'].append(subjectAll)
    for content in contents:
      #Formatting HTML output
      contentAll = content.name + '  ' + content.order
      values['contents'].append(contentAll)
```

Comment: I actually just found a different solution to this question. Rather than formatting the data in HTML, I found it easier to format the data for HTML within the main.py and then send it to HTML.

Comment: Is it generally good/bad practice to format HTML in a python script like I did with my alternative approach rather than doing it in the actual HTML???